# Is Ethereum wallet to wallet token exchange possible?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have been using the decentralized exchange EtherDelta. The idea of a decentralized exchange to me is that I fully own my tokens and directly exchange with others peer to peer (wallet to wallet), i.e. one transaction for one exchange of tokens and pay fee only once. However in EtherDelta you still need to deposit first before exchange and withdraw after that, which result in 3 transactions and triple fees. Is it possible to exchange ERC-20 tokens wallet to wallet (peer to peer), something like atomic swap between Bitcoin and Litecoin? Or my idea of decentralized exchange is totally wrong?
If it is possible, is it very difficult to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the development of Crypto, AMM decentralized exchange (dex) like Uniswap have emerged which truly implement decentrilization and replaced old ones like EtherDelta.

Answer (score -1):

Go checkout below shapeshift website, you can exchange coins there and use wallet.ethereum for wallet to wallet transfer

https://wallet.ethereum.org/
https://shapeshift.io/#/coins

Comment: I know of shapeshift. It's different from what i expect for wallet to wallet transfer.

Comment: Using shapeshift is essentially no difference from selling the first token and buying the other token. The process actually takes two steps and they profit from doing this for you. 
My vision is implementing token exchanging from the code level as smart contract. No intermediary.